# How do I find a dataset with a ground truth(perfect image) to compare a hole filling approach?

Tags: python, database, opencv, spatial, noise

I am using python and OpenCV to perform spatial and temporal denoising on rgb-d images. However, until now I was using data physically captured using Kinect in my lab. But I realised, after hole filling(spatial denoising) I will require a pixelwise perfect depth image meaning, without holes/temporal noise (or groundtruth) to compare the hole filled output. So that I can conclude the efficiency of my approach. I have tried searching for online databases such as KITTY, Middlebury, TUM and Darmstadt dataset but none of them have a perfect .png image I can use as my groundtruth. Is there any such dataset available that could be useful for my application or will I have to create a groundtruth myself by using any tools/plugins to create artificial depth images from computer generated 3D scenes or reproduce depth noise?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using Middlebury dataset, and while they provide the Ground Truth in PFM format, you can easily install the provided CVKIT and from there convert the PFM Ground Truth into PNG. :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).